# SQL logic to find/drop duplicates of column combination

Tags: sql, duplicates, concatenation, logic

Hi I have a sql query that results in the output like this

[image]

I want the output to look something like this:

[image]

Requirement:

1. row should not have duplicate when CONCATENATE(column one + column two) or CONCATENATE(column two +column one)
2. the duplicate value that is lower in column three is dropped

Comment: @Shmiel I am a non-tech grad with limited sql experience and this is definitely not homework, would appreciate help or atleast not being flagged as HW :)

Comment: I am able to do this on excel but thought can do something in SQL

Comment: MySQL version??

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table with itself to find related pairs. Then discarding the unneeded ones becomes easier:

```
select x.*
from t x
left join t y on y.one = x.two and x.one = y.two
where y.one is null or x.one < y.one
```

**EDIT:**

If the values are coming from a query already you can reuse place it as a subquery of this one. For example

```
with t as (
  -- your long query here
)
select x.*
from t x
left join t y on y.one = x.two and x.one = y.two
where y.one is null or x.one < y.one
```

Comment: second line would be 'y' right?

Comment: also what if this is already a long query with multiple select lines?
Is there a way where I can mark them togther as x?